# Ты говорил(,) …

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова

Нужна ли запятая вот здесь: «Ты говорил(,) вы встречались с ней». Я про часть с «Ты говорил». По идее оно выражает неуверенность, но мне кажется, что это даже не вводная конструкция.

Comment: Поясните, почему вам так кажется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это выражение подразумевает опущенное "что". Розенталь в таких случаях рекомендует использовать длинное тире. Но ситуация очень гибкая. Запятая и двоеточие вполне приемлемы, так что выбор остаётся за автором текста. Строгих ограничений тут нет. Кроме одного: оставлять вовсе без знака препинания нельзя. А вообще, активнее пользуйтесь поиском. Подобные предложения уже рассматривали здесь.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь ведь запятая разделяет две грамматических основы: "ты говорил" и "вы встречались". Я думаю, что в первую очередь нужно учитывать это правило, если сомневаетесь.
Как отмечено выше, это сложноподчиненное предложение с пропущенным союзом "что".

Comment: Проблема в том, что "ты говорил" может рассматриваться не предложение, а просто как вводное, где выделение основы не обязательно.